# can't install sonar with JDK 8

Tags: java, error-handling, java-8, sonarqube

I have to install sonar on my machine. I followed [Install Sonar on Windows as a Windows Service](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.com/2012/05/install-sonar-on-windows-as-windows.html).

When I runned `StartSonar.bat`, I saw next output to console:

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Error occurred during initialization of VM
jvm 1    | Could not reserve enough space for object heap
jvm 1    | Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=160m; support was removed in 8.0
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 2    | Error occurred during initialization of VM
jvm 2    | Could not reserve enough space for object heap
jvm 2    | Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=160m; support was removed in 8.0
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 3    | Error occurred during initialization of VM
jvm 3    | Could not reserve enough space for object heap
jvm 3    | Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=160m; support was removed in 8.0
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 4    | Error occurred during initialization of VM
jvm 4    | Could not reserve enough space for object heap
jvm 4    | Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=160m; support was removed in 8.0
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 5    | Error occurred during initialization of VM
jvm 5    | Could not reserve enough space for object heap
jvm 5    | Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=160m; support was removed in 8.0
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
wrapper  | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
wrapper  |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
Press any key to continue . . .
```

***How to solve this issue?***

I understand that reinstall JDK version probably solves this trouble. But I want to keep 
current version:

```
C:\Users\Nazar_Lelyak>java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the [system requirements](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/sonar/requirements), JDK8 is not supported (yet) for the SonarQube server runtime. You will have to use JDK7 instead.

**Update**
Looks like JDK8 is supported for versions ≥ 4.3

Comment: I see the message `Could not reserve enough space for object heap`, what amount of RAM do you have on this machine?

Comment: Installed memory RAM **8 GB**